# How to find my DNS Server address in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dns, ip, troubleshooting

What is the easiest way to know my current DNS server's IP address or domain name? I am trying to troubleshoot my broadband Internet connection under Windows 7.

Comment: Do you mean Ip address? Or are you actual trying to find which name server you're connection is using?

Comment: It sounds like this is your home system, which probably doesn't HAVE a domain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you know your public IP address simply enter in a command prompt window:

```
nslookup <your public IP>
```

You can also specify the name server to check against by appending it to the above command.

You can get your current IP address from sites like http://whatismyip.com

Comment: thats seems fine .. but there was some conflict :( pls see the photo http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua6cT.png any solution? Thanks

Comment: @rakib Means there is no public DNS name for you, or your ISP doesn't give one

Comment: @rakib, please try running "ipconfig /all" as that will give you more details on the problem. You are essentially troubleshooting your internet connection, yes?

Comment: You can just `nslookup` **anything**. It doesn't have to be your own IP address. If you don't provide any parameters, the interactive shell will start and will display the active nameserver right at the top.

Answer (score 71):

You want to open "Run" then type

```
cmd.exe
```

In the command prompt enter this command

```
C:\>ipconfig /all | findstr /R "DNS\ Servers"
```

The output should look something like:
[image]

Comment: That shows the DNS server, not the DNS name

Comment: Since he is troubleshooting his internet it seems he wants to verify he is connected to the ISP DNS server. It is unlikely he even has a DNS address, which is shown in the screenshot he shared

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it directly answers the user's question: "my current DNS server address..." However, on my Windows box the DNS Servers come as a group and not all of them are prefixed with the string. ipconfig /all works, though, if you eyeball it.

Comment: The order printed is not necessarily the same as the order used.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I prefer this approach:

```
echo | nslookup | findstr "Default\ Server"
```

It will print the name of your default DNS server in the shell

Comment: actually a combination of the two answers gives the best result: `echo exit | nslookup | findstr ":"`.
Just using yours in PS prompts "Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject[0]:", while the other one prints unnecessary lines.

Comment: This does not work in `PS` to get a quick result, see Bob's answer for PS.

Answer (score 7):

```
echo exit | nslookup
```

This will show the primary DNS server domain name and IP address.

```
Default Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

>
```

Thanks to @OliverSalzburg's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/486946/139292).

Answer (score 7):

The following powershell command outputs the DNS information in a structured format:

```
powershell Get-DnsClientServerAddress
```

Example output:

```
InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses
                             Index     Family
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------
vEthernet (Default Switch)          21 IPv4    {}
vEthernet (Default Switch)          21 IPv6    {fec0:0:0:ffff::1, fec0:0:0:ffff::2, fec0:0:0:ffff::3}
Wi-Fi                               17 IPv4    {10.0.0.1}
Wi-Fi                               17 IPv6    {2001:123:456:789::1, 2001:123:456:789::2}
```

Comment: Please do not simply post a command without an explanation about what the command does and how to interpret the output.

Comment: Should it have been a comment then?

Comment: No: Your solution is valid... just flesh out your answer a bit with the result of the command and why you think this answers the question...

Comment: @TorstenLink I've made the suggested changes

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought... +1 from me.